# Fazer diferentes combinações de palavras dentro de uma sentença

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Como exemplo tenho a seguinte sentença:

`texto = O gato subiu no telhado de 10m, um homem jogou-lhe uma pedra e ele caiu de uma altura de 20m.`

Quero extrair a seguinte informação:

`(O gato subiu 10m, O gato caiu 20m)`

Tentei:

`(gato).*(subiu|caiu).*(?=m)`

E me retornou apenas

`gato subiu 10m`.

Posso tb usar:

`>>search_1=re.findall(re.compile('gato.*subiu.*(?=m)'),texto)`

`>>search_1=[gato subiu 10]`

`>>search_2=re.findall(re.compile('gato.*caiu.*(?=m)'),texto)`

`>>search_2=[gato caiu 20]`

e depois junto as duas listas.

Mas ainda acredito que deve existir uma forma mais otimizada de escrever isso em apenas uma linha de código.

obs:
As sentenças sempre respeitam essa ordem `[gato / palavra / número seguido de "m"]`

Comment: Mas não há na sua setença `o gato caiu`, tem `ele caiu`. A expressão deve conseguir entender que `ele` refere-se a `gato`?

Comment: Se tivesse a palavra gato duas vezes seria fácil, mas só aparece uma vez.

Comment: Se eu usar `'(o gato).+caiu.+(?=m)'` retorna o que eu preciso, mas dai teria que fazer isso pra cada ocorrência, subiu, caiu... etc.

Comment: Mas primeiro responda nossa dúvida: como você quer que retorne `gato caiu` sendo que não existe esta expressão no texto? Não deveria retornar `ele caiu 20m`?

Comment: A única possibilidade que consigo ver é https://ideone.com/rqHi3v. Mas se a necessidade é que realmente retorne `gato caiu`, necessita-se de um pouco mais de código.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss se eu fizer um codigo para `(o gato).+caiu.+(?=m)'` ele retorna `o gato caiu 20 m`, eu teria que fazer outro código `(o gato).+subiu.+(?=m)` ele reotorna `o gato subiu 10m` dai teria o meu resultado, mas teria que fazer duas buscas e eu queria saber se existe uma forma otimizada sem que eu precisasse fazer outro código  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não se pode fazer com uma única expressão usando o módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) de Python
(embora seja possível com o módulo [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/), criado por [Matthew Barnett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688213/mrab), usando `\G`).

> Adendo (Guilherme Lautert):
>
> A razão do porque você não poder usar a mesma regex para os dois
>   casos, é que regex se usa para encontrar/substituir. E você tem um
>   problema nessa logica.
>
> Veja bem as sentenças que você quer é :
>
> 1. `O gato subiu 10m`
> 2. `O gato caiu 20m`
>
> Você quer capturar `O gato` duas vezes, sendo que ele só aparece uma.
>   Sendo o outro interpretado por `"ele"`. [Veja no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MQt2fk/1). Ou seja
>   `O gato` já foi capturado por isso ele não é capturado novamente.

Use duas expressões, uma para casar o sujeito, outra para casar a palavra e o número, iniciando o casamento no final do último.

**Sujeito:**

```
\b(gato|coelho)\b
```

- `\b` - âncora aos [limites de uma palavra](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/borda.html#2_3_3).

**Sentença:**

```
[^\n.]*?\b(subiu|caiu)\b[^\n.,]*?(\d+m\b)
```

- `[^\n.]*?` - [lista negada](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista-negada.html#2_1_3) que casa qualquer caracter fora linha novas ou pontos (ou seja, na mesma sentença), com um [quantificador não-guloso](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/quantificadores-nao-gulosos.html#3_3) para o menor casamento possível.
- `\b(subiu|caiu)\b` - [grupo](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/grupo.html#2_4_3) 1, para guardar ao verbo.
- `[^\n.,]*?` - mais caracteres, menos linha novas, pontos ou vírgulas.
- `(\d+m\b)` - [grupo](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/grupo.html#2_4_3) 2, para guardar ao número seguido de "m".

---

#### Código

```python
import re

sujeito_re  = re.compile(r"\b(gato|coelho)\b", re.IGNORECASE)
sentenca_re = re.compile(r"[^\n.]*?\b(subiu|caiu)\b[^\n.,]*?(\d+m\b)", re.IGNORECASE)
resultado = ()

texto = "O gato subiu no telhado de 10m, um homem jogou-lhe uma pedra e ele caiu de uma altura de 20m."


for sujeito in sujeito_re.finditer(texto):
    pos = sujeito.end()
    while True:
        sentenca = sentenca_re.match(texto, pos)
        if not sentenca:
            break
        resultado += (sujeito.group(1) + " " + sentenca.group(1) + " " + sentenca.group(2),)
        pos = sentenca.end()

print (resultado)
```

**Resultado:**

```
('gato subiu 10m', 'gato caiu 20m')
```

Pode testar aqui: http://ideone.com/PuQPGH

Comment: Acho que até agora foi o que mais se aproximou. 
Tenho usado:
 `search1 = re.findall(re.compile(gato.*subiu).*(?=m)),texto)` 
e 
`search2 = re.findall(re.compile(gato.*caiu).*(?=m)),texto)` 

e junto as duas listas em uma. Pensei tb em caminhar pelo texto extraindo com search/group a posição da palavra, se houver e checar se ainda existe alguma outra ocorrencia até o final do texto, isso consumiria menos linhas de código.

obs: texto = "O gato subiu no telhado de 10m, um homem jogou-lhe uma pedra e ele caiu de uma altura de 20m."

Comment: @Mueladavc O menor número de linhas de código não significa mais otimizado. Este código é mais eficiente do que usar 2 findall. Como eu respondi, é impossível fazer com uma única expressão, a menos que você use o [módulo regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/).